# dialog opened by electron dialog.showOpenDialog method doesn't show network drivers

Tags: javascript, electron, atom-editor

i develop my app with electron. i opened a dialog by dialog.showOpenDialog method, it didn't show the network dirvers on my computer. But when i used atom(the text editor) to open a dialog, the network drivers came out.  Am i doing this wrong? How can i make it behave just like atom ? These are the screenshoots:

[the network dirve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKsr1.png)

[the dialog my app opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okQki.png)

[the dialog atom opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyAMl.png)